# Custom class file bib not appearing

Tags: biblatex, resume

Using a minimal biblatex example shown below, I am trying to incorporate citations into a resume using a custom [class file](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/medium-length-graduate-cv)

The class file Starts with

```
\PassOptionsToClass{11pt,12pt}{article}
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}
```

so I imagined the behavior should not change if I change the document class as shown in the following example. Ive been searching but cannot find a good explanation.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}    % Works
%\documentclass[margin=1cm, 10pt]{resume} % Doesn't work
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{auth1:2000,
title = {A book},
author = {A. Thor},
date = {2000},
publisher = {Some Company},
location = {A City}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{auth1:2000}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class in the zip is called `res.cls` not `resume.cls` as in your example. Beside this: it contains a `nofiles` command and so doesn't write auxiliary files:

```
  \nofiles       % resume's don't need .aux files
```

Add

```
\let\nofiles\relax
\documentclass[margin=1cm, 10pt]{res}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the help. Adding the relax command resolved the issue.